# Strange behavior using the wildcard character for certain keywords

Tags: lucene, azure-cognitive-search

In my azure cognitive search index, when I search for the term "education", I get 660 hits. When I search for the term "educational", I also get 660 hits. Both seem to return the same results containing both variations of the word alongside one another.

However, I am seeing very strange behavior when using the wildcard character:

```
edu* returns 660 results (expected)
educ* returns 660 results (expected)
educa* returns 2 results (matches two instances of the hyphenated word "educa-tion")
educat* returns 0 results (unexpected)
educati* returns 0 results (unexpected)
educatio* returns 0 results (unexpected)
```

Every search field uses the English Lucene language analyzer and queryType is set to "full" and searchMode is set to "all".

Why aren't the last results returning anything?

As an aside, I found conflicting information about using the wildcard character at the beginning of a word.

The lucene documentation says:

> Note: You cannot use a * or ? symbol as the first character of a
> search.

From: https://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html

But on Microsoft's site, they seem to imply that it should work:

> Term fragment comes after * or ?, with a forward slash to delimit the
> construct. For example, search=/.*numeric./ returns "alphanumeric".

From: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/query-lucene-syntax#bkmk_wildcard

I've tried *ducation (which returns an error) and /.*ducation./ (which returns 0 results).

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the English Lucene analyzer your content is stemmed aggressively. This is explained in the link you provided in the section "Impact of an analyzer on wildcard queries". If you change to the Microsoft English analyzer your example should work as expected.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/query-lucene-syntax#impact-of-an-analyzer-on-wildcard-queries

> If you were to use the en.lucene (English Lucene) analyzer, it would
> apply aggressive stemming of each term. For example, 'terminate',
> 'termination', 'terminates' will all be tokenized down to the token
> 'termi' in your index. On the other side, terms in queries using
> wildcards or fuzzy search are not analyzed at all., so there would be
> no results that would match the 'terminat*' query.
>
> On the other side, the Microsoft analyzers (in this case, the
> en.microsoft analyzer) are a bit more advanced and use lemmatization
> instead of stemming. This means that all generated tokens should be
> valid English words. For example, 'terminate', 'terminates' and
> 'termination' will mostly stay whole in the index, and would be a
> preferable choice for scenarios that depend a lot on wildcards and
> fuzzy search.

Comment: Thank you! If I switch to the En.Microsoft analyzer, do you know if the syntax for boolean operators, fielded search, or proximity search is the same as in that article? I cannot find an equivalent article for the En.Microsoft analyzer.

Comment: The search syntax is the same no matter what analyzer you use.

Comment: This is also what I noticed based on my testing, but it's nice to get confirmation, thank you. Microsoft should really rename the H1 in that article so it doesn't give the impression that it only applies to the Lucene analyzers.